# Deploying AKS in Azure with federatedIdentityCredentials in a single subscription deployment

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-rm-template

Been struggling with this problem for 2 days and multiple queries using ChatGPT, to no avail. Basicallly I want to write an Azure ARM Template that deploys 3 things:

1. "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters" with oidc enabled
2. "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities"
3. and finally 2x "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials" such that I can aquire the oidc profile issuer url and provide it to the properties of the federatedIdentityCredentials

ala something like:

"issuer": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters', parameters('clusterName')), '2021-03-01').addonProfiles.aciConnectorLinux.config.customHeaders['Authorization'].Issuer]"

My main problems are that:

- the first time I deployed this cluster the oidc profile was NOT enabled, even though I provided "enableRBAC": true and "oidcIssuerProfile": { "enabled": "true" }
- when I attempt to use azure cli the show command says there is no issuer url.. I'd rather not have to use the update command to enable it and then later install the federated credentials.

Is there limitation to azure arm templates where they can't access the Issuer Url until the cluster is deployed?

Answer (score 1):

The issuer URL is indeed not available until after the deployment.

I have a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aks-workload-identity/tree/main) that shows all 3 of the steps you are trying to do, in the first stage i create the cluster, after creation i create the user assigned id with fed cred properties.

```
resource app1id 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2022-01-31-preview' = {
  name: 'id-app1'
  location: location
  
  resource fedCreds 'federatedIdentityCredentials' = {
    name: '${nameseed}-app1'
    properties: {
      audiences: aksconst.outputs.aksOidcFedIdentityProperties.audiences
      issuer: aksconst.outputs.aksOidcFedIdentityProperties.issuer
      subject: 'system:serviceaccount:app1:app1-workloadidapp1'
    }
  }
}
output idApp1ClientId string = app1id.properties.clientId
output idApp1Id string = app1id.id
```

Note that my sample is written in bicep (which a. provides a better authoring experience than arm and b. compiles to arm anyway).

---

This is what the ARM Json would look like (i generated this just with `bicep build myfile.bicep`)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.15.31.15270",
      "templateHash": "3913907296451853014"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "nameseed": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myenv"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', 'id-app1', format('{0}-app1', parameters('nameseed')))]",
      "properties": {
        "audiences": [
          "api://AzureADTokenExchange"
        ],
        "issuer": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters', 'aks'), '2023-03-02-preview').oidcIssuerProfile.issuerURL]",
        "subject": "system:serviceaccount:app1:app1-workloadidapp1"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters', 'aks')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'id-app1')]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
      "apiVersion": "2023-03-02-preview",
      "name": "aks",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "enableRBAC": true,
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkPlugin": "azure"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "id-app1",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "idApp1ClientId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'id-app1'), '2022-01-31-preview').clientId]"
    },
    "idApp1Id": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'id-app1')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm unfamiliar with bicep unfortunately. Would the arm template work and generate the issuer url if the aks was in its own "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments", ?

Comment: I'm trying to remember how the json would be structured. I literally never write Arm Json any longer since bicep gained arm feature parity and full support from Microsoft 2 years ago. I can convert thus to arm is that's more familiar to you, but I'd really recommend you look at bicep.

Comment: Ok, added the Arm json.